# How to validate an email address?

Tags: jquery, validation, tags, tag-it

I am using jQuery Tag-It. When I enter the tag value, it needs to be validated if it is a valid email address or not. How can I validate this tag using tag-it?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go!

```
$(".emails").tagit({
    beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        return isEmail(ui.tagLabel);
    }
});


function isEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
```